# Ext.Net Button Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I am using Ext.Net and I have a problem.

I am creating dynamic buttons. It is working but if i click, the button event is not working.:(

How can I fix it?

My code:

```
foreach (var events in eventsInformation)
{
    Ext.Net.Button btn = new Ext.Net.Button();
    btn.ID = events.EvtId.ToString();
    btn.Text = events.EvtName;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Tickets_click);
    ViewPort1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ext.net DirectMethod instead of ASP.NET postback event handler.

```
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" Icon="Lightning">
    <Listeners>
        <Click Handler="Ext.net.DirectMethods.SetTimeStamp();" />
    </Listeners>
</ext:Button>            


<script runat="server">
[DirectMethod]
public void SetTimeStamp()
{
    this.Label1.Text = string.Concat("Server Time: ", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things that require correction in the original sample:

1. By default, Ext.NET Button Components **do not** AutoPostBack (ie, reload the entire page). It is encouraged to use DirectEvents (Ajax call) if you want to communicate with the server and avoid a complete page reload.
2. Ext.NET Components should be added to the parent .Items Collection, instead of the .Controls Collection.

Here's a complete demo with both these corrections.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Ext.Net.Button btn = new Ext.Net.Button();

        btn.Text = "Submit (AutoPostBack)";
        btn.Click += Button1_Click;

        // 1. Set to AutoPostBack, default is "false"
        btn.AutoPostBack = true;

        // 2. Add Button to .Items Collection    
        this.ViewPort1.Items.Add(btn);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Notify("Server Time", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Viewport ID="ViewPort1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I'd recommend changing your AutoPostBack Button Click event to a DirectEvent Click. That would require making the following three revisions to the code-behind.

**Example**

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Ext.Net.Button btn = new Ext.Net.Button();

        btn.Text = "Submit (DirectEvent)";

        // 2. CHANGE to .DirectClick 
        btn.DirectClick += Button1_Click;

        // 3. REMOVE btn.AutoPostBack = true;

        this.ViewPort1.Items.Add(btn);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    // 3. CHANGE "EventArgs" to "DirectEventArgs"    
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Notify("Server Time", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Show();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 from me - If *Mr Ext.Net* can't give the right answer, who can!? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The place to start is the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). If you're programatically adding controls to an asp.net page then you should familiarise yourself with it, if you're not already =)

Now work your way down this checklist:

1. Are you *always* adding the components (buttons in this instance) to the page? If you don't add them *always, then on post-back they won't be there for the EventHandler to be wired up to, for the handler to fire. (This may not apply to an Ext.Net button triggered by a DirectEvent, but it can't hurt).
2. Do you have the "usual" Ext.Net handler/module registrations in your web.config file to enable the direct events to be handled?
3. Have you verified that you're not receiving any javascript client-side errors that are inhibiting the event handler?
4. Use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to verify that the event is actually triggering a DirectEvent back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ext:Button ID="extBtn1" runat="server" Text="Cancel">
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click OnEvent="extBtn1Click">
            <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
        </Click>
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

This extBtn1Click event will fire in server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The button is not present when Event is fired. That is why it doesnt work. If you construct some testing button in aspx file, it would work just fine.

Solution: You must construct the button during OnInit event so it will be present, and bound to EventHandler, during the new page cycle after clicking the button.